# Chrome address bar not hiding on scroll

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, browser

On Chrome 71 on Android, when scrolling down a web page, the browser hides the address bar. This happens on most sites I check (Google news, bbc, our company site etc).

I can't get this to work on my site. The address bar stays fixed no matter how I scroll.

Even when I strip back to the basics it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
        <p>Test Text Test Text</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there something special I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: If your page is hosted somewhere, could you give the url to access it ?

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out the address bar will not hide if you are not using https or have any https issues on your page. Makes sense I guess, so the user can always see there are issues with the page.

Comment: I have same issue on mobile but I have https without issues ( green padlock on desktop navigators) So this solution not working in mi case. Have you found other solutions?